# Can't get <tr> tags when scraping data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all tr tags using BeautifulSoup, but it returns none. Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/defense_advanced.htm'
html = urlopen(url)
stats_page = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

column_headers = stats_page.findAll('tr')[0] #Line that returns none and throws IndexError
column_headers = [i.getText() for i in column_headers.findAll('th')]
```

Even though there are tr tags in this url, it returns none and throws an `IndexError`. Why is this happening?

Comment: The page content is probably loaded using JS. Do `print(html)` to see what data beautiful sees

Comment: Ok, I'll try that

Comment: It returns `<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x10af29700>`. Do I need to do html.read()?

Comment: Do `print(html.read())`.

Comment: Just checked. The stats table is loaded via javascript.

Comment: @DeepSpace Out of this context, _to see what data beautiful sees_ is poetry

Comment: @PaulH Ha! I meant to write beautifulsoup... I'll leave it for future generations to enjoy as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page source table is located inside comment. You need to extract comment content and then parse it as HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment

url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2020/defense_advanced.htm'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
comment = soup.find(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment) and 'class="table_outer_container"' in text)
stats_page = BeautifulSoup(comment, "lxml")
column_headers = stats_page.findAll('tr')[0]
column_headers = [i.getText() for i in column_headers.findAll('th')]
```